# How to sum values for multiple columns in DataTable using Groupby with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by, sum

I have a simple DataTable as the following:

```
column1 value1  value2
ee      1       2
ee      2       4
ee1     3       6
ee2     3       3
ee2     4       2
```

I want to get the sum of value1 and value2 by each colunm1, lastly get a new DataTable as the following:

```
column1 value1  value2
ee      3       6
ee1     3       6
ee2     7       5
```

It`s not too difficult to realize by a loop of calculation in a traditional way.
I want to realize that as simple as possible in a Linq way.
I have a existed solution, but I don`t like it very much.Especially, here I had to use the Foreach to realize it, it`s a little weird.

```
var resultDt = dtIn.Clone();
dtIn.Select().GroupBy(m=>m["column1"].ToString())
             .Select(n=>new 
                          { Row = n.First(),
                            Value1 = n.Sum(s=>(int)s["value1"]),
                            Value2 = n.Sum(s=>(int)s["value2"])
                          })
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(m=>
                      {
                          var drNew = m.Row;
                          drNew["value1"] = m.Value1; 
                          drNew["value2"] = m.Value2;
                          resultDt.Rows.Add(drNew);
                      });
```

Somebody who can give me a hint?

Comment: I just hope who can share me a much smarter way to realize the sum and group by..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smarter way is usually to do the aggregate on the database side to avoid filling unnecessary data.

The loop can be hidden in a `.Aggregate`:

```
var result = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToLookup(r => r[0] as string).Aggregate(dt.Clone(),
    (t, g) => t.Rows.Add(g.Key, g.Sum(r => (int)r[1]), g.Sum(r => (int)r[2])).Table);
```

or a bit more complicated for multiple columns:

```
DataTable result = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToLookup(r => r[0])
    .Aggregate(dt.Clone(), (t, g) => t.Rows.Add(Enumerable.Range(0, t.Columns.Count)
    .Select(i => i < 1 ? g.Key : g.Sum(r => (int)r[i])).ToArray()).Table);
```

---

```
Debug.Print(string.Join("\t", result.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName)));
Debug.Print(string.Join("\n", result.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => string.Join("\t\t", r.ItemArray))));
```

Answer (score 3):

using [CopyToDataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var resultDt = dtIn.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(m=>m.Field<string>("column1"))
                 .Select(n=>new 
                              { column1  = n.Key,
                                Value1 = n.Sum(s=>s.Field<int>("value1")),
                                Value2 = n.Sum(s=>s.Field<int>("value2"))
                              }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks for you quickly reply. In your method you use the CopyToDataTable() ,  I just don`t know what the column will be defined in the resultDt

Comment: you will get column1, Value1, Value2  as coulmn names

Comment: Thanks you method, it basically solve my problem. But I still have a deep question, if there are a lot of columns, in your solution, I have to define each column the the new { column1 = xx,  column2 = yy, *****}. In fact, what I really want is just get the sum in the value1, and value2, the other column will use the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Here give this a try, this should work for you:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("column1");
dt.Columns.Add("value1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("value2", typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add("ee", 1, 2);
dt.Rows.Add("ee", 2, 4);
dt.Rows.Add("ee1", 3, 6);
dt.Rows.Add("ee2", 3, 3);
dt.Rows.Add("ee2", 4, 2);

var items = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
            x => x.Field<string>("column1")
    ).Select
    (
        n => new
        {
            column1 = n.Key,
            value1 = n.Sum(z => z.Field<int>("value1")),
            value2 = n.Sum(z => z.Field<int>("value2"))
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   In your solution, we had to use a loop to put all the elements to the resultDataTable from the the items.  So there is no too much different from my former solution.