# How to get the sum of multiple columns of a datatable in c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I want to get the sum of only three columns for each data row in datable. I have a DT with approx 15 columns and I only want the sum of column 7, column 9 and column 10. And all the columns are of string type.
I tried few methods using LINQ but all failed.

Comment: All columns are strings but you want to sum them? What type do they represent actually, double, decimal, int?

Comment: could you provide more detail about how the datatable looks like, code,...?

Comment: Check This Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991525/how-to-sum-values-for-multiple-columns-in-datatable-using-groupby-with-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all columns are strings but actually represent floating point numbers:

```
double totalSum = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Sum(r=> double.Parse(r[7].ToString()) + double.Parse(r[9].ToString()) + double.Parse(r[10].ToString()));
```

If some are empty or have invalid numbers you need to use `double.TryParse`.

Comment: thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, it worked for me even if the column type is of string:

```
for (int i = 11; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 14; j <= 18; j += 2)
    {
        if (j > 17)
            j -= 1;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString()))
        { 
            newdt.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i][18], dt.Rows[i][19], 
            dt.Rows[i][j]);
        } 
    }
}
    
try
{
    var result = 0;
    if (newdt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {                          
        result = newdt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["Column7"]));
        subdt.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i][18], dt.Rows[i][19], result) 
    }
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).